# How do I extract specific parts of an argument and put them in their own variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, arguments, discord, discord.js

So I'm trying to get the name and id of an emoji in discord (discord.js) out of the argument but don't know how to do that

All I'm given is **<:hack_wump:670702611627769876>** and i need **var id = '670702611627769876'** and **var name = 'hack_wump'**.

How exactly do I strip the argument of <::> and put the extracted parts in their own variable?

Comment: you have 2 options, or manipulate the string for example `a.replace('<','').replace('>','').split(':')` and that will give you an array with you can extract the data you want, or go by an `regex` syntax that I'm sure many that know it better can come up with :) - I always tried to avoid regex, makes my head dizzy :P [here's how by using string manipulation](https://i.imgur.com/bEN8wYr.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
const str = `<:hack_wump:670702611627769876>`;
const [name, id] = str.slice(2, -1).split(':');
console.log(name, id);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it like this:

[`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to remove the `<` and `>`

[`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to split into an Array of Strings

Finally, using [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to assign the variables you want

```js
let args = '<:hack_wump:670702611627769876>';

let [_, name, id] = args.replace(/<|>/g, '').split(':');

console.log(name);
console.log(id);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex, `/<:([^:]+):([^>]+)>/`, to group and match your variables.

```js
var match = /<:([^:]+):([^>]+)>/.exec('<:hack_wump:670702611627769876>');
```

match will then be an array with 3 elements:

- match[0] = "<:hack_wump:670702611627769876>"
- match[1] = "hack_wump"
- match[2] = "670702611627769876"

For more regex details, please refer to:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [*match*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to get sequences of characters that aren't part of the markup. E.g.

```js
let s = '<:hack_wump:670702611627769876>';
let [name, id] = s.match(/[^<:>]+/g);

console.log(`name: ${name}, id: ${id}`);
```